# Minimal polynomial of a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

I just need to see an example of a non-diagonalizable $4\times4$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ whose minimal polynomial is the same as its characteristic polynomial.

I saw the question elsewhere and became much interested, but I am unable to construct such matrices.

Comment: The companion matrix of any degree$~4$ monic polynomial with at least one multiple root will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda& 1&0&0\\ 0&\lambda &1 &0\\ 0&0&\lambda& 1\\ 0&0&0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$.The characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial are $(x-\lambda)^4$.

Comment: Then how do we know that it's not diagonalizable or similar to a diagonal matrix?

Comment: It is a Jordan block. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: Another way to see that it is not diagonalizable : an endomorphism/the corresponding matrix over a field $\mathbb F$ is diagonalizable  iff the minimal polynomial factors completely over $\mathbb F$ into distinct linear factors.

Comment: Alternatively, call the matrix $A$. Since $A$ is non-diagonalisable iff $A-\lambda I$ is non-diagonalisable, we may consider only the case $\lambda=0$. When $\lambda=0$, note that $A^4=0$. However, the only diagonalisable matrix such that its some $k$-th power is zero is the zero matrix. Hence $A$ is not diagonalisable.